# Intellij IDEA doesn't grey out some unused methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In intellij IDEA, if a method is unused, the method is shown in a gray color. But in some cases, IDEA doesn't grey out the method, but when I check the references of those methods using alt + F7, IDEA says that the method is unused.

Is this a IDEA bug or is there any reason why IDEA wouldn't grey out these specific methods? If it is a bug, is there some workaround to make IDEA identify that method is unused?

Comment: In eclipse it never warns of public or protected methods. Maybe it is the same here?

Comment: Do your methods implement an interface?  This means that even though the method is not used it cannot be removed.

Comment: This happens when you are implementing methods of an Interface and this is not a bug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely it's not a bug, it's a limitation for performance reasons. Methods likely to take a long time when searching for usages are skipped.

A workaround is to run Unused Declaration inspection explicitly in all your project via Analyze | Inspect Code or Analyze | Run Inspection by Name. That'll take some time. You can also set up TeamCity server to do it for you automatically every night.

Answer (score 4):

I used to have it working like charm, but one time, I by mistake clicked on alt+Enter on an unused method, and chose to suppress the inspection on unused code. Ever since then, I stopped getting the grayed out methods and code, so since there is a way to get it undone, there sure must be a way to get it back working.

After 5 minutes of searching, I found a solution:

Settings --> Editor --> Inspections --> Java --> Declaration Redundancy --> Unused Declaration

Make sure you check "Unused Declaration"

And I just checked by creating a new useless method, working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is quite late, but perhaps it will help others to identify their problem:

IntelliJ didn't mark methods as unused for me, because they were overloaded methods, for example:

```
    1: methodName(String argument)
    2: methodName(ArrayList<String> argument)
```

The first method was no longer used, but the second method was. IntelliJ (I assume) simply checks the method names, and sees that the method name is used, even though one of them is no longer used.

I have checked the other answers on this page for finding unused methods, but have not found a solution to filter out unused, overloaded methods.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug if you're using a method with a very common name.

If you tried @Peter Gromov method above, and your method is still yellow, it might be the case that this is a bug.

I had a very common named method, named "stop".

- Looking for usages (using ALT + F7) didn't show anything.
- Analyzing the whole project, clearly showed that this method did not have any use.

Despite that, the method was still yellow.

I was surprised to find out, that if I try to refactor the method name, I get a pop-up warning that this will change in other places as well.

Turns out, that the refactoring warned about changing the method name in TODO comments. Somehow Lint recognized the TODO comments as using this method.

My advice is to just not name your methods as something that may be written in a TODO comment.

See this image, where I am using a method named "stop" :
[image]