# IDEA shows method as in use, when it is not

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Why does IDEA show this `SimpleClass.start` method as in use:

[image]

Even when it is not.  Changing the name of the method to something else then greys it out as not in use:

[image]

Seems to not only happen with `start` but also `init` and `stop` for ones I've tried.  Am using version 13.1.4 on Windows.

Comment: Whole code? Screenshot? We don't see anything from here. Does your class extend anything or not?

Comment: whole code yes, adding screenshot to original post

Comment: Could it be because it's a `public` method, and so it could be used from an external project ?

Comment: @imrichardcole i tried your example with Idea 2016.2.5 an is working correctly

Comment: Well, who knows. Seems pretty random to me. Why is it bugging you that much anyway? :D Try to clean/rebuild/restart IDEA. If that doesn't fix it, just ignore it :)

Comment: @Vucko - but how can I rest until I know?  On a serious note, we believed a piece of code was being used when it wasn't, it was picked up as part of code refactoring and tidy up.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds legit. But I've never encountered that with and JetBrains products, they're usually pretty spot on.

Comment: My hunch is that maybe some keywords are actually stopwords for which they don't check as there is a big chance they might be used from inheritance or from another source. It doesn't make too much sense, just a guess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij IDEA doesn't grey out some unused methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047689/intellij-idea-doesnt-grey-out-some-unused-methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a performance optimisation.

- Basically IntelliJ IDEA ***first*** checks its index for occurrences of the ***name*** of the method.
- Then it checks in the file of every occurrence to see if it's really a usage of that method.
- If the ***name*** of the method is used in ***many places***, many files will have to be parsed and checked. To ***avoid*** taking ***too much time*** and cpu for that, the check is skipped if there are more than a certain amount of occurrences in the index and it ***assumes*** that the method is ***used*** (Since the probability is very high).
- Running the ***unused declaration*** inspection in batch mode (`Analyze > Run Inspection by Name...`) will still report the method as ***unused***.

Comment: No. I have expanded my answer to make more clear what I mean.

Comment: Good explanation. Hope u r pretty sure with this fact. Anyway assuming unused method as used is not harmful, but not the other way around. :))