# IntelliJ IDEA greys out some unused methods but not all

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.6 I have the following Java class.

```
public class EinzUnregisterResponseMessageBody extends EinzMessageBody {

    private final String username, reason;

    public EinzUnregisterResponseMessageBody(String username, String reason){
        this.username = username;

        this.reason = reason;
    }

    /**
     * @return the body as JSONobject, ready to be included as "body":{this returned Object} in a message
     */
    @Override
    public JSONObject toJSON() throws JSONException {
        return new JSONObject("{\"username\":\""+this.username+"\"," +
                "\"reason\":\""+this.reason+"\"}");
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
}
```

IntelliJ usually displays unused properties in light grey. In this class, it only greys out `getReason()`.
It makes sense that it does not grey out the constructor or the fields. The method `toJSON()` is defined in the abstract superclass `EinzMessageBody` and thus has to exist, so it is correct that this is not greyed out either.
`getReason()` is never used and thus greyed out. **But why is `getUsername()` not greyed out?**
When I right-click it and select *Find usages*, IntelliJ reports that no usages are found.

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047689/intellij-idea-doesnt-grey-out-some-unused-methods), but running *Analyze>Inspect Code* and *Analyze>Run Inspection By Name>Unused Properties* don't seem to have any effect on this. Neither does restarting the IDE.

*Invalidate Caches and Restart* first resets the display so that nothing is greyed out, but once it finished Indexing, the highlighting is again the same.

Here's how it is displayed in IntelliJ
[image: How it looks like for me]

The superclass `EinzMessageBody` only specifies `toJSON()` and neither `getReason()` nor `getUsername()`.

What is the difference between `getReason()` and `getUsername()` ?

Regarding @HonzaZidek's comment:

- Removing the `extends EinzMessageBody` and the annotation `@Override` does not change anything.
- Creating a completely empty project and pasting only this class and `EinzMessageBody` makes everything greyed out except the `toJson()` method. This is as expected because I am now not instantiating the class - thus the constructor being greyed out, and both `getReason()` and `getUsername()` behave the same (both greyed out).

  - This still behaves as expected when I move the classes to different subpackages, like they are in my real project setup.
  - This still behaves as expected when I instantiate the Class: The constructor stops being greyed out, `getReason()` and `getBody()` are still correctly greyed out.

I just pulled on my Laptop (as opposed to the Desktop PC) and the same behaviour happens there as well.

I searched also for any usages of `getUsername()` on other subclasses of `EinzMessageBody` and found one. Removing this one did not change the `getUsername()` in `EinzUnregisterResponseMessageBody` to be greyed out though.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40870673/2550406) suggests to run *Analyze>Run Inspection By Name>Unused Declaration*, because IntelliJ might not check commonly used names for performance reasons. That lists both `getReason()` and `getUsername()` as unused, but the display style remains the same.

Comment: Unrelated, but your code will break if username or reason ever contain a double quote.

Comment: Thanks! This was only intended as a stub, but I would probably have missed that :)

Comment: Well then, is it a web application? Haven't you the field referenced from a web page? Or from an XML configuration? IntelliJ is intelligent enough to mark the getter `getUsername` as *used* even if it is only referenced as the `username` field. The paid version does show these places in "Find Usages", but I am not sure if the community version does. You should consider the `username` as a *property* (even if Java does not embrace the concept), at least IntelliJ evaluates the field and its accessors (setters and getters) together.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, and no it is not a web app. It's for android. I do not have any resources that I know of referencing this class

Comment: Another hint: try the extended `Find Usages` dialog by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`F7` and check what and where exactly you are searching. If this does not help, create a copy of your application, and then remove one file after another until the method name become gray :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek I didn't find the time yet to try removing files, but `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`F7` returns also no usages found when searching in "All Places", including "Overriding Methods", "Usages" and "Text usages"

Thanks for your help btw :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that it really is, as you suspect, the optimization built-in into IntelliJ Idea. You may report it as a bug or feature request in [JetBrains's Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) - at least there would be nice having the option to turn the optimization off.

Following the existing answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/32049386/2886891 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40870673/2886891, I am adding a reference to the IntelliJ Idea's description under `Settings` | `Editor` | `Inspections` | `Java` | `Declaration Redundancy` | `Unused declaration`:

> Some unused members might not be reported during in-editor highlighting. Due to performance reasons, a non-private member is checked only when its name rarely occurs in the project.

[image]

Comment: Ah, so that means even if I run this, it does not change the display style. Okay, all clear now, thanks!